# Python decorator to support static properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, meta-programming, static, properties

Classes in Python do not have native support for static properties. A meta-class can rather easily add this support as shown below. Are there any problems programmers might experience if they use this implementation?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
class StaticProperty(type):
    def __getattribute__(cls, name):
        attribute = super().__getattribute__(name)
        try:
            return attribute.__get__(cls, type(cls))
        except AttributeError:
            return attribute

    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        try:
            super().__getattribute__(name).__set__(cls, value)
        except AttributeError:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)


class Test(metaclass=StaticProperty):
    __static_variable = None

    @property
    def static_variable(cls):
        assert isinstance(cls, StaticProperty)
        return cls.__static_variable

    @static_variable.setter
    def static_variable(cls, value):
        assert isinstance(cls, StaticProperty)
        cls.__static_variable = value

    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        assert isinstance(self, Test)
        return self.__value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        assert isinstance(self, Test)
        self.__value = value


def main():
    print(repr(Test.static_variable))
    Test.static_variable = '1st Hello, world!'
    print(repr(Test.static_variable))

    instance = Test()
    print(repr(instance.value))
    instance.value = '2nd Hello, world!'
    print(repr(instance.value))

    assert Test._Test__static_variable == '1st Hello, world!'
    assert instance._Test__value == '2nd Hello, world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My first inclination is that the `property` class should be sub-classed as `static_property` and should be checked for in `StaticProperty.__new__` to ensure it is being used properly.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want class properties? Properties that are bound to the class not the instance.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, but the example code seems to illustrate that both kinds of properties are possible. Some might find it confusing, though, if there is no distinction between a class and instance property.

Answer (score 4):

- You've masked a bug, in `__setattr__` a property raises an `AttributeError` if the setter hasn't been defined. This causes you to overwrite the property.
- (As you've said) There's no distinction between a class property and an instance property. You can change it so there is, but it doesn't allow the property to only be defined on the class, not the instance.
- You can just define the static properties on the metaclass. This removes a lot of the headaches.
- If you *really* want to define everything onto the class not the metaclass then you can make the metaclass hoist the wanted functions into a new metaclass. This means everything works as if you only defined two metaclasses with the properties correctly defined.

No fancy changes:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    @property
    def class_(self):
        return self._class

    @class_.setter
    def class_(self, value):
        self._class = value

    @property
    def class_instance(self):
        return self._class_instance

    @class_instance.setter
    def class_instance(self, value):
        self._class_instance = value

class Test(metaclass=MyMeta):
    class_instance = MyMeta.class_instance

    @property
    def instance(self):
        return self._instance

    @instance.setter
    def instance(self, value):
        self._instance = value
```

Hoisting:

```
class classproperty(property):
    pass


class classinstanceproperty(property):
    pass


class StaticProperty(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, props):
        class_properties = {}
        to_remove = {}
        for key, value in props.items():
            if isinstance(value, (classproperty, classinstanceproperty)):
                class_properties[key] = value
                if isinstance(value, classproperty):
                    to_remove[key] = value

        for key in to_remove:
            props.pop(key)

        HoistMeta = type('HoistMeta', (type,), class_properties)
        return HoistMeta(name, bases, props)


class Test(metaclass=StaticProperty):
    @classproperty
    def class_(self):
        return self._class

    @class_.setter
    def class_(self, value):
        self._class = value

    @classinstanceproperty
    def class_instance(self):
        return self._class_instance

    @class_instance.setter
    def class_instance(self, value):
        self._class_instance = value

    @property
    def instance(self):
        return self._instance

    @instance.setter
    def instance(self, value):
        self._instance = value
```

---

These both pass the following tests: (I could only get your approach to work with instance and class instance)

```
test = Test()
test._instance = None
test.instance = True
assert test._instance is True
assert test.instance is True
test.instance = False
assert test._instance is False
assert test.instance is False

Test._instance = None
Test.instance = True
Test.instance = False
assert Test._instance is None
test._instance = True
if Test._instance is not True:
    print("instance can't be used after modifying class")

Test._class_instance = None
Test.class_instance = True
assert Test._class_instance is True
Test.class_instance = False
assert Test._class_instance is False

test = Test()
test._class_instance = None
test.class_instance = True
assert test._class_instance is True
assert Test._class_instance is False
test.class_instance = False
assert test._class_instance is False

Test._class = None
Test.class_ = True
assert Test._class is True
Test.class_ = False
assert Test._class is False

test = Test()
test._class = None
test.class_ = True
assert test._class is None
assert Test._class is False
test.class_ = False
assert test._class is None
```